# PHP registration profile info

Tags: php, registration, profile

I am working on a new project and just finished the registration system. The idea is that after the registration, at the first login, the user is asked to provide more information to fill his profile. This consists of 3 or 4 steps, one of them is the ability to invite friends to this website.

I have a few questions about this proces and hope this is the right place to ask.

1. I am thinking there should be a check on whether this is the first time the user is logged in or not. What is the best way to achieve this? Setting a field(firstlogin) in the mysql database to 1 and checking for it? This way I have to do this check every time the user logs in. Is this the best way to it or is there another better/easier way?
2. How can I achieve the 3/4 steps profile fill in? Is there an existing framework or something to do this or do I have to code it myself?

Comment: 1. You can check if the additional information has been input already and if not, show the continued registration process. 2. just take it page by page submitting the information to the database each time and continuing. || Check out [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for proper questions to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your questions:

1. Try to take advantage of your current schema before adding more fields. Use a field that is present already on someone's profile. For example, you may have a field called `last_login_date`. By default you will have it set to null. If it is null, the user has never logged in before, else the field has a date in it and thus indicates that he has entered at least once before.
2. If the steps' input information should be stored even if not all steps are complete then you must take record somewhere (database) that he is on X step currently and submit his inputs at each step. On the other hand, if the steps are not that critical, you can store his inputs within the session cookie and submit it after the 4/4 step completion in one go.

Answer (score 1):

i personally think for the last question you don't need a framework for do this.
However for the first step, i suggest to you (as you said) to add to mysql a boolean field called firstlogin and in everypage you check

```
<?php 
        include("database_connection_etcetera.php");
        if ($user['firstlogin'] == 0)
            {
                // show add fields
            }
        else
            {
                // show what you would have shown normally
            }
?>
```

For the second question what your problem?
You just do a simple html form where you put (for example) occupation, company name, address.. etc..
and with a simple mysql INSERT you put in into the table users where id is the $user['id'].

Make sure to have already added the fields occupation, company name, address... etc.. in the mysql database and put it as NULL (DEAFULT NULL). SO there are no trouble!

All right? i hope yes, im here for everything you need,
best regards.

Comment: The tricky part with a multi-form registration is that you need to make sure they don't skip out at any portion. Which means, you set the boolean at the end but that may cause them to repeat parts of the process because they skipped the last page. It depends on the final goal of what each page does, just something to consider.